# How to set fixed property of element when rotate (using CSS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, jquery-mobile

I'm dev an app for WP8 using HTML5.
My CSS code

```
@media all and (orientation:portrait) {
@-ms-viewport {
    width:320px;
    user-zoom: fixed;
    max-zoom: 1;
    min-zoom: 1;
}
#sample{ display:none}
@media all and (orientation:landscape) {
@-ms-viewport {
    width:480px;
    user-zoom: fixed;
    max-zoom: 1;
    min-zoom: 1;
}
#sample{ display:block}
```

And in my Javascript file

```
if($('#sample').css('display') == 'none') {
    $("#sample").fadeIn("slow");
}else{
    $("#sample").fadeOut("slow");

    }
```

In my HTML file have a button. When I click on this button, #sample show/hide. But when I hide it, I rotate my device to lanscape, it disapear. 
I want  #sample always show in lanscape mode. Anyone can help me? Thanks all .

Problem fixed : Use orientationchange event

```
 $(window).on("orientationchange", function (event) {
            if (event.orientation == "landscape") {
                $("#sample").fadeIn("slow");
            } else {
                $("#sample").hide();
            }
        });
```

Comment: your script can be just simple as `$('#sample').fadeToggle('slow')`

Comment: ***when I hide it, I rotate my device to lanscape, it disapear*** this is confusing, you've already hidden it, of course it dissappeared, to show it again, click your button. Unless you meant the **it** as another thing.

Comment: Thank you, but do you know how to keep it display when rotate to lanscape?

Comment: I'm not sure about the event triggered when the orientation is changed, but you can try adding some style `display:block` in the @media rule for `orientation:landscape`.

Comment: I added display style in landscape mode. But it's still not work

Comment: I've tried the `orientationchange` event in jQuery mobile and looks like it works, instead of using pure JS, you can try `$(window).on('orientationchange', function(e) {/* check the e.orientation property here */})`

Comment: Oh. I got something wrong when using orientation event. But now it's OK. Thanks for your help :D

Comment: Considering you're using jQuery, you may as well use something more semantic like `$('#sample').is(':hidden')` instead of `$('#sample').css('display') == 'none'`.